# "in" keyword not enough in Python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
x = ["Hello", "World"]
y = ["Hi", "Guys"]
z = [x, y]
```

The following line will return False:

```
"Hello" in z
```

But I need a way to make it return yes. I need a way to control if an object is in one of the lists contained in z. The only way is a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

You do need some kind of loop, yes, because `"Hello"` is indeed not in `z` -- it is in `x` which is in `z`:

```
>>> x = ["Hello", "World"]
>>> y = ["Hi", "Guys"]
>>> z = [x, y]
>>> "Hello" in x
True
>>> x in z
True
>>> any("Hello" in a for a in z)
True
```

In the expression above, `a` iterates over `x` and `y`, and we check to see if `any` of those values of `a` satisfies `"Hello" in a`.

Here's a similar-but-different approach which flattens `z` (using nested `for` loops) before using `in`:

```
>>> [b for a in z for b in a]
['Hello', 'World', 'Hi', 'Guys']
>>> "Hello" in (b for a in z for b in a)
True
```

As before, `a` iterates over each list in `z`, and now within that iteration we have `b` iterate over each string in each `a`, which produces a single iterable that contains all four strings; we can then use `"Hello" in`  (that iterable) and get the desired result.